# Whether wildcard "*" includes newline characters or not in word's find and replace

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, find, find-and-replace

I'm getting really inconsistent behavior with this, and not just for hard and soft returns, but for hard returns.  I can't work out whether there is a bug with the behaviour here or if I'm doing something wrong.
Should `the*quick*brown*fox` find the text as follows, or not or not?

[image]

as plaintext for completeness:

Introduction to this document. 
`the thing is that this blah blah
a whole bunch of unrelated stuff
quick brown
a bunch more stuff
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et fox`es are cool 
dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip

Comment: Can you show us a version with paragraph marks and other formatting symbols shown? That'll help people tell the difference between separate paragraphs, hard returns, and line wrapping.

Comment: oops, I forgot to.  But all hard returns apart from the lorem ipsum which is line wrapped..  Sometimes it searches across the lines, then you highlight the same hard return, type a new one, and it no longer does.  Then on saving the document, it does again.  Very strange.